# Custom CSS/ Logo & Title

Tags: html, css, squarespace

I am trying to see if I can find a way to use CUSTOM CSS or HTML for my website's logo on Squarespace. The maximum pixel count is 320 and my logo is still small. I am trying to find a way around this by coding it. I am new to coding Custom CSS and HTML and would like some help as to how I can center my logo on each and every page at a larger pixel amount . By using an image block possibly and just centering my logo.

Comment: Hi Bryanna, you need to show us that you've made some effort, provide the code that replicates the problem you're trying to solve along with clear details on what you're trying to achieve and a description of anything you've tried that didn't work. *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve]."*

Comment: so my site is https://www.goodemoments.com/ . If you look you can see that my logo image is smaller than what I would like it to be. I really don't know what to do or how to make it larger since the pixel size is at its max, I need help or some sort of direction as to how I should make my image larger , but also keep it as my main home page link.

Comment: Bryanna, the point of stack overflow is to be a resource for specific programming problems. Your website will likely change over time and may not even be available, which means that when people happen upon this post in the future, if all you do is link to your website, and the site has changed or is unavailable, this post will be useless since folks can't reference the original code for the problem. You need to include your code **in the post itself**. Read the link I posted about creating a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

I have inspected your page and found your problem.

In `.Header-branding-logo` the `max-width: 320px;` made every sizing effort of yours useless since the maximum width is only 320px, which is not big enough according to you.

So, I deleted that and modified the code as follow

```
.Header-branding-logo {
  width: 200%;
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
}
```

So now, the logo's width is twice as much as the container `top-center`'s width. `position:relative; left:-50%;` is for centering your logo.

Like Michael have mentioned in his comments, you should have provided the code replicating the problem inside your question so people could have a nicer look to invest your problem.